# Merge two array of objects together es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6

Currently I have two different array of objects and my end result is I am trying to have one single array of objects.

```
const postIds = [
  { id: 4938960132 },
  { id: 5586491011 },
  { id: 4671908225 },
  { id: 4594788047 },
  { id: 4657970305 }
]

const images = [
  { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/rustic20coffee20table.jpeg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
  { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/Amazing-Table-For-Flamboyant-Furniture-Home-Design-Ideas-With-Rustic-Furniture-Coffee-Table.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
  { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/envoy-lookout-rooftop-11b-780x520.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
  { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/Alexanderplatz_03.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
  { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/mountain-landscape-wallpaper-29048-29765-hd-wallpapers.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' }
]
```

What I am hoping to have at the end is a data structure like the following

```
const newData = [
    { id: 4938960132, featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/rustic20coffee20table.jpeg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
    { id: 5586491011, featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/Amazing-Table-For-Flamboyant-Furniture-Home-Design-Ideas-With-Rustic-Furniture-Coffee-Table.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
    { id: 4671908225, featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/envoy-lookout-rooftop-11b-780x520.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg'  },
    { id: 4594788047, featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/mountain-landscape-wallpaper-29048-29765-hd-wallpapers.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg'},
    { id: 4657970305, featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/mountain-landscape-wallpaper-29048-29765-hd-wallpapers.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' }
]
```

I've been trying a lot of different things here such as reduce, spread operator and other es6 functions but cannot seem to get the data structure that I am looking for.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: what's the logic for merge ? I don't see how id is matched with the image url in anyway

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two arrays have the same length:

```
const newData = [...postIds.map((postId, i) => Object.assign({}, postId, images[i]))];
```

Alternativelly, with `...` operator:

```
const newData = [...postIds.map((item, i) => {
  return { 
    ...item,
    ...images[i]
  };
})];
```

Working snippet:

```js
const postIds = [
  { id: 4938960132 },
  { id: 5586491011 },
  { id: 4671908225 },
  { id: 4594788047 },
  { id: 4657970305 }
]

const images = [
  { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/rustic20coffee20table.jpeg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
  { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/Amazing-Table-For-Flamboyant-Furniture-Home-Design-Ideas-With-Rustic-Furniture-Coffee-Table.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
  { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/envoy-lookout-rooftop-11b-780x520.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
  { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/Alexanderplatz_03.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
  { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/mountain-landscape-wallpaper-29048-29765-hd-wallpapers.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' }
]

const newData = [...postIds.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, images[i]))];

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You creduce both array by mapping the objects at the same index and by assigning to a new object.

This works for an arbitrary count of arrays.

```js
const
    postIds = [{ id: 4938960132 }, { id: 5586491011 }, { id: 4671908225 }, { id: 4594788047 }, { id: 4657970305 }],
    images = [{ featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/rustic20coffee20table.jpeg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' }, { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/Amazing-Table-For-Flamboyant-Furniture-Home-Design-Ideas-With-Rustic-Furniture-Coffee-Table.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' }, { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/envoy-lookout-rooftop-11b-780x520.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' }, { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/Alexanderplatz_03.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' }, { featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/mountain-landscape-wallpaper-29048-29765-hd-wallpapers.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' }],
    result = [images, postIds].reduce(
        (r, a) => a.map((o, i) => Object.assign({}, o, r[i])),
        []
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```